# Why does not the vector content be erased?

Tags: c++, vector

If v1 is cleared, will the contents disappear in v2? Why does not it disappear? What is the reason?

```
vector<string> v1;
vector<vector<string>> v2;
v1.push_back("a");
v1.push_back("b");
v2.push_back(v1);
v1.clear();
```

Comment: Because you're putting a **copy** of `v1` into `v2`. Any changes to the original `v1` aren't affecting the copy in `v2`.

Answer (score 0):

your assign is a copy,not origional v1.
after you put v1's copy into v2,they are seperted.
so,no matter what you have done to v1,it won't do anything to v2.
you can try to understand how does the vector do , assigning operation are copy not reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your v1 data is delete after copy to v2,
v2 has been save v1 data ,so it is not affect to v2

Answer (score 0):

Great question. This is the type of question that we all have to ask ourselves over and over to understand what is happening to the memory that is being used.  When a vector element is created by pushing another object into the vector...

```
v2.push_back(v1);
```

a copy of v1 is made for insertion into v2.

std::vector keeps all memory contiguous, so there is rarely an opportunity to avoid this copy when using std::vector.

With other types of STL containers, it may be possible to avoid the copy if v1's life comes to an end at the time of the insertion, which would imply the use of a move constructor.  However, that is typically not going to happen with std::vector.